# Find next greater number with zeros in sql number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to find next greater number starting by 1 and followed by zeros in Microsoft SQL. Numbers could vary in digits. ie:

Query: 9856, Result after procedure: 10000
Query: 98999, Result after procedure: 100000

Thanks.

EDIT: There is no chance of having negative numbers. This is a calculation for a energy meter. For example, numbers can go up to 99999 or 999999 or 9999999. When energy overcome that number, it will start again at 0. So I can't read what energy has been used in that period. To know it, I need to calculate the number as asked, then perform some basic maths.

There is no need for knowing what is going on on 10, 100, etc, because of the nature of the operation. It will only be used when the above escenario happend.

Comment: Any negative numbers? What's the result for 0 and 1?

Comment: For 10 or 100 what should be the result?

Comment: Added an edit for further explanation, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you require or mathematically any other formula can be implemented. but technically that can be achieved as follows

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 1000

DECLARE @result INT

SET @result = CASE WHEN @count%10 = 0 THEN @count ELSE CAST('1'+REPLICATE('0',LEN(@count)) AS INT) end

SELECT @result
```

Comment: I was about to post `CONVERT(int, '1' + REPLICATE('0',LEN(9856)))`. Though it only works for values greater than 0

Comment: yes. I didn't get case of 10-100-1000 so added one condition now

Answer (score 2):

This works for positive numbers (numbers greater than zero):

```
select power(10, ceiling( log10(the_number) )) from mytable;
```

In case the number is already a power of ten (1, 10, 100, ...) , the number itself is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just arithmetic operations:

```
select power(10, floor(log(v.n - 0.1, 10)) + 1)
from (values (1), (10), (8), (9982), (124)) v(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly crude way of doing it, however it does work. The query basically looks at the number of digits your number has, assumes the next integer you want starts with a 1 and then adds the relevant number of 0's to it.

Note this only looks for the next increment and does not round down.

Also for 10 you will get 100 and for 1000 you will get 10000.

```
declare @number int = 98999;
declare @len int = len(@number);
declare @stringtoreturn nvarchar(200)='1';

declare @runs int = 1;

while @runs<=@len
    begin
    select @stringtoreturn = @stringtoreturn + '0';
    select @runs=@runs+1;
    end

select @stringtoreturn;
```